# Why do some foreign english speakers preface people's names with the definite article "the?"

Tags: definite-article

I work with people from various nationalities and I've noticed over the years that they use The when referencing someone by name, for example

> Today I was talking to THE Bob about lunch.

Has anyone noticed this? It's curios and wondered if it might have something to do with their native language.

I work with Hindus and east Asians.

Comment: A large number of native speakers do this too.  It is just a figure of speech.

Comment: @Chenmunka could you explain more about this figure of speech and the contexts it's used in?

Comment: How are we supposed to know why some non-native speakers speak as they do? Yes it might have something to do with their native language, it might not.

Comment: Where you may have more than one Bob to whom you may be referring.  Often *The* Bob is used to ensure the listener knows who you mean.  It does of course require both parties to have an understanding of who that is.

Comment: *Your* sentence is a bit off. I agree with @Chenmunka, *the* could happen to appear in some contexts. But the example you've provided is very unlikely to be said in a grammatical sentence.

Comment: If I were to say this, I would by implying something like: "Today, i was talking to The One and Only Bob at lunch."  This would imply, sarcistically or truly, that Bob was a Celebrity and that talking to him was something very special.  "I talked to The Bill Gates / Barack Obama, today!"

Comment: The example I gave is clear about what I mean. The point is, the name of the person is prefaced by the definite article. "The Jim told me something was wrong." "Yesterday, the Betty was not home."

Comment: @Chenmunka I've only ever heard "the" used like that in phrases like "the Bob who works here", "the short Bob", etc. Without further words to clarify which is being referred to, how does the word "the" "ensure the listener knows who you mean"? Do you mean that you've heard "the" used as sort of a synonym of "this" or "that"?

Answer (score 2):

This can be a part of speech in some languages and as such, learners of English may naturally carry this across when speaking **whether they know this is wrong or not**. This can be because when we speak, generally our language is being produced spontaneously and sometimes traits of our mother tongue can slip in.
This is certainly true of my Catalan students of English (in Catalan the definite article precedes people's names).

Answer (score 0):

I've been waiting for someone to answer this, and have been asking a few of my coworkers if they posted it ;-)

- I've noticed myself prefixing `the` before names. I make mistakes in English mostly when I'm stressed beyond a level. I can't explain this particular one as anything more than an inertia in thought process. Maybe I used `the` in my previous sentence or sometime recent vocabulary.
- Another way I could justify Indian and Chinese folks saying this could be that words like `the` are easier to pronounce amongst the articles and closer to the native accents. Same way some words are easier for americans to say like `Ummm...` before sentences.

Btw I'm Hindu, its a religion and it has absolutely nothing to do with it. What you might be referring to are the people from non-english speaking asian countries.

Comment: HA, no it wasn't your coworkers, it was me. I meant Indian (not native american)