# [The]: Why "I know the tower's height" but "I know Bryan’s height"?

Tags: definite-article, possessives

- I know `the` tower's height — with `the`
- I know <strike>the</strike> Bryan’s height — without `the`

### Questions:

1. What's the general rule for using `the` with possessive (`'s`)?
2. In the first sentence `the` is used because of definite tower or definite height?

Comment: It's simple: The determinant (the, a, an) before the substantive. Maybe there are exceptions, but I don't know.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59739/why-do-some-foreign-english-speakers-preface-peoples-names-with-the-definite-ar#comment114432_59739

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your second question first: In the first sentence, `the` refers to the tower, not the height.

That's the answer to your first question, too: in your examples, the `the` has nothing to do with the possessive `'s`. You could remove "height" and read the sentences this way (with "know" meaning "to be familiar with" instead of "to be aware of a fact"):

- I know the tower.
- I know Brian.

People's first names don't require an article in English, but countable nouns like "tower" do, so there you have it. You could also rewrite the sentences as:

- I know the height of the tower.
- I know the height of Brian.

"Height" takes the article both times, but "Brian" still doesn't need it.